# text in textview disappears on adding an image view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am using linear layout. I have an imageview and a nested linear layout. Inside inner linear layout, I have two textviews. When I add an imageview below the second textview, text in second textview disappears . I have no idea why is this happening. Can someone help ?

XML file : (layout  for one cell of listview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_paackage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/row_click_imageView1"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/more" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you checked displaying package name in log or toast?

Comment: It might be null

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem @MoFaizanShaikh

Comment: Happy I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your Code according your code , Here showing all `textView` with `imageView`. Also check is it not getting `null` on that `text`.

Try with below code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Heading Text"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_paackage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Heading Text2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/row_click_imageView1"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/more" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```